Not displaying permission dialog for camera permission
In my app I try to check and request for camera permission. But unfortunately, it is not showing the permission dialog. I tried on different phones. but still no luck. not able to understand what is the issue. app is :
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 34 Could anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here.
Code:
public class ScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String resultValue;
private static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);
    // Retrieve the parameter.
    storagePermission();
    resultValue = getIntent().getStringExtra("myParam");
    saveBooleanInSp("imageSavedStatus", false);
    checkAndRequestCameraPermission();

}


private void checkAndRequestCameraPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Request the camera permission
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // Permission already granted, start the camera or crop activity
        startCropActivity();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted, start the camera or crop activity
            startCropActivity();
        } else {
            // Permission denied, show a message to the user
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera permission is required to take pictures",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

